# Что означает length?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, необходимо подсчитать кол-во Number of categories. Подсчитала:

```
const ItemCategoriesEl = document.querySelector('ul').children.length;
console.log('Number of categories:', ItemCategoriesEl);
```

, но не могу понять что дает `length`?

Comment: мне больше интересно как вы посчитали, если не знаете что такое length и что он даёт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length` длина коллекции `HTMLCollection`, которую возвращает свойство `children`. Коллекция - это "сколько-то штук" элементов одного типа. `length`- это и есть "количество штук"

Comment: Алексей, благодарю!

Comment: Я не умею читать такой код в одну строку